# If $V\cong X$ and $W\cong Y$, then $V\otimes W\cong X\otimes Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, canonical-transformation

The question is very straightfoward: It's true that given real vector spaces $V$, $W$, $X$, $Y$ such that $V\cong X$ and $W\cong Y$, then $V\otimes W\cong X\otimes Y$? And if it's true, what is the prove of the unicity, exaclty? I could prove that exists an isomorphisms betwen them, but I couldn't prove the unicity.

Here $\cong$ means that there exists a canonical isomorphism betwen them.

Comment: "There exists a canonical iso" does not mean there is a unique iso. But if you are given isos $f$ and $g$ ("canonically"), that certainly implies that you are given the iso $f \otimes g$ ("canonically"). However, there are others (usually/sometimes; it depends on extra data) e.g. $-7f\otimes g$ (assuming $7 \not= 0$).

Comment: @peterag I'm confused. I read that an isomorphism is canonical if it is unique. What canonically means, then?

Comment: “When I use a word,’ Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, ‘it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.’

’The question is,’ said Alice, ‘whether you can make words mean so many different things.’ But take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_map.

Comment: "Canonical" isn't precisely defined, it just means there's in some sense an obvious choice. For instance, there's a canonical isomorphism from $V \otimes W$ to $W \otimes V$ mapping $v \otimes w \mapsto w \otimes v$, but there's no reason to believe that's the only one.

In particular, you could compose any isomorphism with a nontrivial automorphism of either your domain or codomain (assuming one exists) and get a new, different isomorphism.

Comment: We/I don't mean to be glib... Certainly your statement "an iso is canonical if it is unique" is reasonable/valid, and important (I tried, but failed, to find a quote from Grothendieck to Serre on this). However, the converse "it is unique if it is canonical" is what we are questioning. However, when there is extra(?) data, and only one (iso)morphism that preserves that data, it is fair/customary to call it 'canonical.'

Comment: @peterag I understand, thanks